# Dual Monitor Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, multiple-monitors

I bought a radeon 4550 graphics card and have two monitors. One monitor is connected to the card as VGA to VGA. Another monitor is connected as hdmi to DVI. I want both monitors to display the same desktop.

My power supply on my computer is just 300 W, but i'm wondering if it's safe to have two monitors running or would I need a higher power supply to support both monitors running at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Your computer power supply has nothing to do with running two monitors... they get power from their own power connections, and only data from the pc.

Most Radeon 4550 based cards are cheap little things, I don't see any that require a separate power connection other than what they get from the pcie bus, so there's no way loading them up with a bunch of work is going to draw enough power to really matter. And even then, mirroring the same screen on both is going to reduce the GPU workload, not increase it.

Answer (score 1):

Whether your power supply is overloaded is going to depend mostly on the other components in your computer and how much power they use when you're running whatever it is you're showing off, as [the Radeon HD 4550 itself uses less than 20 watts](http://www.xbitlabs.com/articles/video/display/ati-radeon-hd4550_4.html#sect0).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this answer if you are concerned about overloading your PSU.

[How much will a 300w power supply run?](https://superuser.com/questions/17683/power-supply-calculator-who-is-to-be-trusted/17704#17704)